# Tampermonkey replace a divs class from hide to show

Tags: tampermonkey

I'm sure this will come off as easy for someone, but for me I'm struggling with it a bit because I don't come across this much and just wanted to create a simple Tampermonkey script to show this div by default on the site if it's attribute is set to hide.

The line of code from the view source/inspect of the website is below:

```
<div id="ProductInventory-7122324111111" class="product__inventory hide">
  74 in stock
</div>
```

If I do a inspect and simply replace `"product__inventory hide"` to `"product__inventory show"` it displays instantly on the website. Is there anyway to do this likewise in a Tampermonkey script?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide more background details on your problem. Telling readers about your research, what you have already tried, and why it didn't meet your needs will allow them to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one element, you can try the following:

```js
// find the element
// ECMAScript 2020 aka ES11 Optional Chaining ?. (continues if found)
// replace hide with show
document.querySelector('.product__inventory.hide')?.classList.replace('hide', 'show');
```

If there are more than one:

```js
// find all the elements
// for each one, replace hide with show
document.querySelectorAll('.product__inventory.hide').forEach(item => item.classList.replace('hide', 'show'));
```